# On dropdown click, close all other dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

When I click on top menu link "menu item 01" 3 level drop down open regularly it is OK, After that click on "menu item 04" mega menu is open it is OK

BUT I want, when user click on any other top menu link  previous all drop down item should hide, only one drop down visible at one time.

Please check [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/ag46ct2u/6/)

```
 var mymenu = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 781px)")
if (mymenu.matches){
$(function() {
$('.navstyle-list li a, .navstyle-submenu li a, .navstyle-submenu-sub-sub  li a').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.navstyle-submenu').toggle(300);
  $(this).next('.navstyle-submenu-sub').toggle(300);
  $(this).next('.navstyle-submenu-sub-sub').toggle(300);
  $(this).next('.megamenu').toggle(60);
});

$(document).click(function(e){
  var target = e.target;
  if (!$(target).is('.navstyle-list li a, .navstyle-submenu li a, .navstyle-submenu-sub-sub  li a') && !$(target).parents().is('.navstyle-list li a, .navstyle-submenu li a, .navstyle-submenu-sub-sub  li a')) {
    $('.navstyle-submenu, .navstyle-submenu-sub, .navstyle-submenu-sub-sub, .megamenu').hide(100);
  }
});
});
}
else{

}
```

Comment: None of the menu items seem to open at all?

Comment: i want make look like that
http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/143/index.html

Comment: This isn't animated, but is this the kind of thing you were looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/ag46ct2u/8/ done with a tiny bit of jQuery to add and remove the classes and then css to decide what to do with those classes

Comment: If that's what you wanted let me know and I'll add the answer with animation.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd drop down is not open.

Comment: That's to do with your css overriding my css due to it being too specifically coded.

Comment: Here you go, I don't advocate or suggest you should use important styling but I don't want to go around fiddling / fixing the rest of your styles, am adding this to the answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Close One Javascript Drop Down Menu When Opening Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46576431/how-to-close-one-javascript-drop-down-menu-when-opening-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't advocate or suggest that you should use important styling, but your css could be simplified a lot so that this wouldn't be necessary and I don't want to refactor all of your css.

The solution is to add the open class to the list item, it's styling then affecting whether or not the child should open.

There is also a check in place so that the open class is only removed from the list item if you are click to a new list item.

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    if(!$(this).parents().hasClass('open')){
        $('li').removeClass('open');    
    }
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ag46ct2u/9/

How you could remove the very specific styling and unnecessary duplication, you would need to re add the styling to the list items. But this gets rid of all of the unnecessary .navstyle-submenu, .navstyle-submenu-sub and .navstyle-submenu-sub-sub

```
li ul {
    display: none;
}

li.open > ul, li.open > div {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I'll add some code to my solution about how you could possibly remove the very specific css

Comment: How to close all drop down when i click on body part?

Comment: You could change it around so that instead of listening for clicks on the anchor tag, you could listen to clicks on the body and where it is hitting, I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: That's ok, but there is a bit of unnecessary duplication and more events than necessary. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/ag46ct2u/11/

Comment: Also, if I were you I would stick do declaring events by using the .on(event, function(){});  style

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78018/discussion-between-dan-and-ravi-gadhiya).